# Grouping unique rows from max column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
query   | update_date | website_id | device  | page    | impressions | clicks | position
--------+-------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+----------
kitchen | 2018-05-01  | 2          | desktop | http... | 11000       | 50     | 3
table   | 2018-05-01  | 2          | desktop | http... | 7000        | 40     | 3
kitchen | 2018-05-02  | 2          | desktop | http... | 11500       | 55     | 3
table   | 2018-05-02  | 2          | desktop | http... | 7100        | 35     | 3
```

I want to make a output where I get the best performing row in regards to `clicks` for each unique `query`. The table above should give the following output:

```
query   | update_date | website_id | device  | page    | impressions | clicks | position
--------+-------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+----------
table   | 2018-05-01  | 2          | desktop | http... | 7000        | 40     | 3
kitchen | 2018-05-02  | 2          | desktop | http... | 11500       | 55     | 3
```

What I have so far is this:

```
select 
    q.* 
from
    (select 
         query, 
         max(clicks) as clicks 
     from 
         search_console_query   
     where 
         update_date >= '2018-05-01' and 
         update_date <= '2018-05-31' and 
         website_id = 2 
     group by query) as t
inner join 
    search_console_query q on q.query = t.query and q.clicks = t.clicks
```

This doesn't work as expected, as I get multiple rows if two rows have the same amount of clicks. Can anyone help me figure this one out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE (query NVARCHAR(MAX)
                        ,update_date DATE
                        ,website_id INT
                        ,device NVARCHAR(MAX)
                        ,page NVARCHAR(MAX)
                        ,impressions INT
                        ,clicks INT
                        ,POSITION INT
                        )
INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ('kitchen', '2018-05-01', 2, 'desktop', 'http...', 11000, 50, 3),
        ('table  ', '2018-05-01', 2, 'desktop', 'http...', 7000, 40, 3),
        ('kitchen', '2018-05-02', 2, 'desktop', 'http...', 11500, 55, 3),
        ('table  ', '2018-05-02', 2, 'desktop', 'http...', 7100, 35, 3);
WITH    cte
          AS (SELECT    *
              ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY query ORDER BY clicks DESC) RN
              FROM      @table
             )
    SELECT  cte.query
     ,      cte.update_date
     ,      cte.website_id
     ,      cte.device
     ,      cte.page
     ,      cte.impressions
     ,      cte.clicks
     ,      cte.POSITION
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   RN = 1
```

Should be close enough.

Will only show one row per query, and you can adjust the order by to decide which row should be prioritised if need be.

Adding more fields to the partition by would allow you to group by other options. e.g. group by query per month, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` function with *TIES*:

```
select top (1) with ties *
from search_console_query s
where . . .
order by row_number() over (partition by query order by click desc);
```